# Not getting data in return with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

This is the data I'm trying to get

```
public function dohvatiZadatak($id){
    $this->id = $id;
    $conn = $this->connect()->prepare("SELECT * FROM zadatci WHERE id=:id");
    $conn->bindParam('id', $this->id);
    $conn->execute();
    $zadatak = $conn->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return json_encode(array('zadatak' => $zadatak));
}
```

Ajax request

```
function urediZadatak(id){
      $("#uredi-zadatak-modal").modal('show');
      $.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         url: "../zadatci/uredizadatak.php?id="+id,
         data: id,
         async: false,
         success: function(response){
             console.log(response.zadatak);
         }
       });
 }
```

I'm getting nothing in return. How do I get that data I'm returning with PHP?

Comment: Aside from the issue, remove `async: false`. It's terrible practice to the point that the browser will give you a warning in the console telling you not to do it. Your code itself looks fine. I'd suggest checking the network tab of the console after you make the request to check what the response is - I would assume you have a server-side issue somewhere in the PHP.

Comment: What *is* the server returning?  A blank response?  An error?  Is there a JavaScript error in the browser's debugging console?  Anything in the PHP error logs?  You need to do some debugging.  Side note: `async: false` shouldn't be used, and browsers are likely to stop supporting it entirely.

Comment: Are you calling `echo dohvatiZadatak($id);` somewhere?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thank you, but nothing changes when I remove that line.

Comment: @David In network tab I'm getting blank response

Comment: @PedroHenrique umm no

Comment: So when function is called, I appears in network tab, and it's Preview/Response tabs are empty

Comment: @V.Alen: A blank response is often an indication of an error in PHP.  Turn on error reporting, check PHP error logs, etc.  Additionally, it's worth examining why specifically you expect response content.  Your PHP code shows a function, but does anything ever invoke that function?  How have you confirmed that function is being invoked at all?

Comment: @David yes I do have file uredizadatak.php which is calling that function dohvatiZadatak with passed id

Comment: If switch 'return' with 'print_r' I get right data in response tab, but it's not usable if I do it with print_r, right?

Comment: @V.Alen: When you call this function, what do you do with the result?  Do you echo it to the output?

Comment: @David I have this in file urediZadatak.php.

if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $zadatak = new Zadatak();
    $zadatak->dohvatiZadatak($id);
}

So I guess nothing yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the response to be sent back from PHP you need to use `echo`. On your code you should add the following to the place calling `dohvatiZadatak($id)`:

```
echo dohvatiZadatak($id);
```

And than on your front-end you can use:

```
function urediZadatak(id){
    $("#uredi-zadatak-modal").modal('show');
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "../zadatci/uredizadatak.php?id="+id,
        data: id,
        async: false,
        success: function(response){
            var parsedResponse = JSON.parse(response);
            // use the response as parsedResponse.key
        }
    });
 }
```

Comment: It works, thank you, and thank you for saving me time for searching how to actually access that data.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the comment thread above...

Your function returns a result:

```
return json_encode(array('zadatak' => $zadatak));
```

But you're not printing that result to the output:

```
$zadatak->dohvatiZadatak($id);
```

All you need to do is print it to the output:

```
echo $zadatak->dohvatiZadatak($id);
```